# Regex to extract multiple URLs

Tags: regex

I would like to extract all Category values for DoubleClick URLs that sit within all of the web source code across a full site ;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var axel = Math.random() + "";
var a = axel * 10000000000000;
document.write('<iframe src="https://1234567.fls.doubleclick.net/activityi;src=1234567;type=examp123;cat=examp999;ord=1;num=' + a + '?" width="1" height="1" frameborder="0" style="display:none"></iframe>');
</script>
<noscript><iframe src="https://1234567.fls.doubleclick.net/activityi;src=1234567;type=examp456;cat=examp888;ord=1;num=1?" width="1" height="1" frameborder="0" style="display:none"></iframe></noscript>
```

What I would like to extract is as follows;

- Cat 1 = **examp999**
- Cat 2 = **examp888**

I have tried the below from @AnkitMishra answer;

```
https:\/\/(?:.*.doubleclick.net).*cat=([^;]*);
```

This returns both values - however the tool I am using to crawl all pages of a website only returns one match per regex.  It doesn't support multiple values, so it returns the first match.  How can I create a 2nd string, to capture the 2nd Cat value?

If one cat value is a default, i.e. defau123 - can I use something like this, within the rule above, to ignore cat values of defau123, but pass anything else?

^((?!defau123).)*$

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can extract all the URLs, loop over them and get the value of `cat` param.

Comment: @PhilBarnes Try this `(?<=cat=)[\w]+`  [Demo here](https://regex101.com/r/qB3wS0/1)

Comment: Try this : http://regexr.com/3cm8m

Comment: Thanks @AnkitMishra, that did the trick for me. My problem now is, the crawler I am using only returns the first match. It doesn't allow multiples.  

If I use your answer to return Cat 1 - `https:\/\/(?:.*.doubleclick.net).*cat=([^;]*)` how could I return Cat 2 in a new request? I don't think end Script or end Iframe will be unique enough?  I have tried this but to no avail - `doubleclick.net.*https:\/\/(?:.*.doubleclick.net).*cat=([^;]*)`

Comment: Why not use just `http:\/\/\S+?\.doubleclick\.net\b\S*\bcat=([^;]*)`?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying be more selective in your regex, then you need to expand your regex to match more data. If you can use look behind then ensure `><iframe src="` is before your URL.

```
(?<=\>\<iframe\ src\=\")https:\/\/(?:.*.doubleclick.net).*cat=([^;]*);
```

[regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/yI5eW8/1)

If look behind is not available or if `><iframe src="` is not reliable, then you will need to find your own reliable anchor.